# How can i deduce the value is being stored in EAX?

Tags: assembly

So i have these instructions:

```
0x0000000000400602 <+69>:   call   0x4004b0 < strcmp@plt >    
0x0000000000400607 <+74>:   test   eax,eax   
0x0000000000400609 <+76>:   jne    0x400617 < main+90 >
```

I read that eax stores strcmp return value, but how can i deduce this? I can't see any instruction for strcmp's return value to be stored in eax register.

Comment: `eax` is the return register for cdecl. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: You need to look at the instructions for `strcmp` itself, if you want to see the instructions that `strcmp` uses to put its return value in `eax`.

Comment: the `call` will redirect CPU to the `strcmp` implementation (i.e. instructions executing the whole strcmp logic), and those instructions will set `eax` to particular return value before executing `ret` to make CPU jump back onto your `test eax,eax`. The `eax` then already contains the result value, so there's no need "load" it somehow from anywhere, the `test` is directly checking if the return value of `strcmp` was non-zero (`jne` will then jump to `main+90` in such case), or follow with next instruction after `jne` when result was zero.

Comment: Maybe you think the `eax` is like local variable in C, i.e. the `strcmp` has no direct way to set it? It's completely other way around, the registers are like "super globals", the single CPU core has at any particular moment only single set of registers (on the front end toward programmer, modern x86 CPU does internally use hundred+ of them and keep dynamically rename them for better performance, but that's not affecting the original single-set logic). So the `strcmp` is working with the same registers, clobbering some of "yours" and you have to know the calling convention used to know which.